# How to get specific time from next day

Tags: go

I want to create a `time.Time` for an exact point in time the following day (tomorrow). For now I would like to set the hour and minute.

This is the code I use at the moment:

```
now := time.Now()
tomorrow := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), 15, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).AddDate(0,0,1)
```

This will create a `Date` for today with the exact time (hour and minute) I am looking for and then adds one day to that `Date`. This works fine.

---

**Example:**

Imagine `time.Now()` is `2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC`.

The result of the following code would be: `2009-11-10 15:00:00 +0000 UTC`

```
tomorrow := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), 15, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
```

To this date I add one day using `AddDate(0, 0, 1)`. The result is then the desired time the next day: `2009-11-11 15:00:00 +0000 UTC`.

See: https://play.golang.org/p/OKR9V1HN50x

---

**Question:**

Is there a shorter way to write this code?

Comment: are you looking for a shorter way to write the same code, which my not be as efficient?

Comment: @OrYaacov Only if the shorter version is as efficient or more efficient than my current implementation. I just started learning Go, so all of this is hard to judge for me. In general I am interested in the most idiomatic solution. Since I am learning I would like to have a solution that does not feel un-idiomatic to seasoned Go coders ;)

Comment: I wanted to suggest PeterSO's version, a bit more efficient, but not shorter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> import "time"
> ```
>
> The month, day, hour, min, sec, and nsec values may be outside their
>   usual ranges and will be normalized during the conversion. For
>   example, October 32 converts to November 1.

---

This is more efficient. It minimizes calls to package `time` functions and methods.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(now.Round(0))
    yyyy, mm, dd := now.Date()
    tomorrow := time.Date(yyyy, mm, dd+1, 15, 0, 0, 0, now.Location())
    fmt.Println(tomorrow)
}
```

Output:

```
2019-06-21 16:23:06.525478162 -0400 EDT
2019-06-22 15:00:00 -0400 EDT
```

---

Some benchmarks:

```
BenchmarkNow-8                  31197811            36.6 ns/op
BenchmarkTomorrowPeterSO-8      29852671            38.4 ns/op
BenchmarkTomorrowJens-8          9523422           124 ns/op
```

`bench_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func BenchmarkNow(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        now := time.Now()
        _ = now
    }
}

var now = time.Now()

func BenchmarkTomorrowPeterSO(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        // now := time.Now()
        yyyy, mm, dd := now.Date()
        tomorrow := time.Date(yyyy, mm, dd+1, 15, 0, 0, 0, now.Location())
        _ = tomorrow
    }
}

func BenchmarkTomorrowJens(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        // now := time.Now()
        tomorrow := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), 15, 0, 0, 0, now.Location()).AddDate(0, 0, 1)
        _ = tomorrow
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. And Go is "clever" when you add one day (`dd+1`) and roles over "intelligently". For example: When you use this on `2019-12-31` it will "role over" to `2020-01-01`. Wonderful. See: https://play.golang.org/p/bFxCywISXav

Comment: @Jens: In Go terminology dates and times are normalized.